# How update Table pyQT5

Tags: python, database, pyqt5

[image]

I want the data to be updated after clicking the button update, but it dont work. please tell me how to implement this. I try to close the window, call the function LOADDATA and open it again, but nothing happens. The data remains, but in database information deleting

```
import sys, os

from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

import mariadb

try:
    connection = mariadb.connect(
        user="root",
        password="******",
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
        database="vista")
except:
    print("...")

cursor = connection.cursor()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("workplace.ui",self)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 35)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 75)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 75)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(3, 70)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["ID", "NAME", "PHONE", "DATE"])
        self.loaddata()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.delete)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.update)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.exit)

    def loaddata(self):
        tablerow = 0
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM vista.workplace ORDER BY 'id'")
        value = cursor.fetchall()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(40)
        for row in value:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[1]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[2]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[3]))
            tablerow += 1
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.loaddata)

    def delete(self):
        idplace = self.lineEdit.text()
        cursor.execute(f"DELETE from vista.workplace WHERE id = '{idplace}'")
        connection.commit()
        print("Deleting!")

    def update(self):
        self.close()
        self.loaddata()
        self.show()
        print("Update!")

    def exit(self):
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: *What* data do you want to update? Is the problem in the `delete()` function? Or are you trying to edit items in the table and you expect that just doing it would update the database somehow?

Comment: @musicamante I need to update the table display. everything else works

Comment: Sorry but "update the table display" is not clear. Please try to explain yourself better.

Comment: Now I have a table displayed in the widget, and I also have the "delete" and "update" buttons. The logic is that the user will enter the ID of the row and delete it, then click on update and the table should be displayed without the row deleted by the user

Comment: Then it probably means that the `delete()` function doesn't work properly. Does it actually print `"Deleting!"`?

Comment: "deleting" function works

Comment: Why are you using `setRowCount()` with an arbitrary row number? If the database contains 40 rows and you delete one, you should clearly *not* have 40 rows anymore, unless you want to *clear* that row, which is a different thing: you removed the row from the database, but you didn't remove it from the table. Besides, what if the database contains more than 40 rows?

Comment: Okay, how to do it right?

Comment: `setRowCount(len(value))`?

Comment: You're cool! Thank you very much, everything worked out

Comment: @musicamante I read your answers to other questions on this topic) You are a professional! I have a question, maybe you can help me) Is it possible to draw the input field maybe in Photoshop, and how to link it with lineEdit?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to customize the appearance of QLineEdit? There are various ways to achieve that, starting from [Qt Style Sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html). Take your time to read all the pages of that documentation, do lots of experiments and thorough testing, and if you still don't get what you want, create a new question.